# Add and remove elements from html and from array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to add and remove elements from a page, but also from the array where the data is stored.

I can add just fine, but I don't know how to detect which button is pressed, and then remove that both from the html and from the array "magazines".

This is my code so far:

```
var magazines = [];

$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    // get all the inputs into an array.
    var $inputs = $('#addMagazine :input');

    // get an associative array of just the values.
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function () {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    magazines.push(values);
    buildList();
});

function buildList() {
    //Clear the list before printing again
    $("#result").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < magazines.length; i++) {
        $("#result").append("<li>" + magazines[i].magazine + " : " + magazines[i].number + " : " + magazines[i].year + "<button>remove</button>" + "</li>");
    }
}
```

And here it is with the html http://jsfiddle.net/FP4BB/8/

The end goal is to store the array in local storage, but for now I just need to find a way to remove entries?

Comment: ***which button is pressed*** in your demo of course it's just the submit button (the only one). ***and then remove that*** remove what? I don't think you mean *that* here refers the button submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, event delegation. Using that will simplify the event binding for your button.

Second point, add a data on the button that give the position in the array. Like that :

```
$("#result").append("<li>" + magazines[i].magazine + " : " + magazines[i].number + " : " + magazines[i].year + "<button data-pos='" + i + "'>remove</button>" + "</li>");
```

Then, remove the button base on the index :

```
$('#result').on('click', 'button', function(){
    magazines.splice($(this).data('pos'), 1);
    buildList();
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FP4BB/10/

Comment: Thanks, works great! But this "data-pos", I understand what it does here, but I don't understand how it works. Maybe you could point me to some place where I can read more about it?

Comment: @Blargmode Yeah, sure. The best place to learn jQuery is the jQuery site itself! You can read the [`data API`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FP4BB/9/)**

```
$(document).on('click','button:not("#submit")',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

This is the code to remove the elements on Click of 'Remove'.

To work with adding handlers for dynamically generated elements, use delegation.

And `button:not("#submit")` to activate event for specific button.

Answer (score -1):

How 'bout using data attributes to assign each item an index when it's added to the DOM, which would correspond to its index in your array? Then you just check the index when it's removed and remove the appropriate item from the array. Another option would be to use a templating language like handlebars.js